# At what velocity would the ruler be thrown from the perspective of someone on earth?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

A super child aboard a space ship moving at 0.7c throws a 50 cm ruler towards the front of the ship at a speed of 0.4c (relative to the ship). If a stationary observer observed the ruler, how long would it appear?

I'm assuming I should use the length contraction formula, but from what I understand that formula is for the distance between two points through which the object travels, not the length of a ruler. That distinction matters because to connect the time dilation formula to the length contraction formula, the velocity for both observers would have to be the same. However, the length of the ruler isn't connected to that velocity since it is not the distance traveled by an object so is it even proper to use this formula?
If the answer is yes, then what would the v in the formula be? The velocity the ruler flying relative to the ship or to the observer? Out of curiosity how would you calculate the latter (using regular mechanics the speed of the ruler relative to the stationary observer would be 1.1c, but that's impossible right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a homework question, so I'll try not to directly answer.

The first think you ask is, the length of the ruler couldn't possible be connected to the velocity... right? And you would be right, a ruler moving faster doesn't make it shrink or dilate. However, it does have to do with how long it *appears to be* to an observer. That is, a metre stick with 100cm markings on it will still have the same markings after length contraction (duh) but the spacings *as they appear* will seem shorter. However, an observer traveling alongside the ruler still measures accurately with the ruler (since the markings are still correct)

The natural question afterwards then is, if two people disagree on the length of a ruler, then surely there must be a contradiction? If not, there must be a scenario in which the length of the ruler matters, so we can derive a contradiction? The answer is no, not really. The reason there is no contradiction (hint, more SR) essentially comes from the fact that you are using classical reasoning on relativistic systems. You do not find a contradiction, even if observers (moving at different velocities) observe different things. (specifically, time duration and simultaneity can be violated in SR)

Finally, how can we find the velocity of the ruler with respect to the earth? Classically, we would add the velocity vectors together, how do we do it here? (Perhaps there is a Special Relativistic rule of adding velocity vectors?)